# Problem adding "Network Policy and Access Services" role in Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, installation, windows

We are encountering an Error Code 0x80070643 when attempting to add the "Network Policy and Access Services" role on a fresh **Windows Server 2008 R2** installation. Is there a known solution for this problem? Here is what information we have available so far:

**From ServerManager.log...**

```
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:01.712 [CBS]                       installing 'IAS NT Service RasServerAll RasRoutingProtocols ' ...
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:01.911 [CBS]                       ...parents that will be auto-installed: 'RasServer '
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:01.912 [CBS]                       ...default children to turn-off: '<none>'
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:01.924 [CBS]                       ...current state of 'IAS NT Service': p: Staged, a: Staged, s: UninstallRequested
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:01.924 [CBS]                       ...setting state of 'IAS NT Service' to 'InstallRequested'
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:01.935 [CBS]                       ...current state of 'RasServerAll': p: Staged, a: Staged, s: UninstallRequested
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:01.935 [CBS]                       ...setting state of 'RasServerAll' to 'InstallRequested'
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:01.946 [CBS]                       ...current state of 'RasRoutingProtocols': p: Staged, a: Staged, s: UninstallRequested
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:01.946 [CBS]                       ...setting state of 'RasRoutingProtocols' to 'InstallRequested'
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:01.956 [CBS]                       ...current state of 'RasServer': p: Staged, a: Staged, s: UninstallRequested
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:01.956 [CBS]                       ...setting state of 'RasServer' to 'InstallRequested'
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:01.967 [CBS]                       ...'IAS NT Service' : applicability: Applicable
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:01.977 [CBS]                       ...'RasServerAll' : applicability: Applicable
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:01.987 [CBS]                       ...'RasRoutingProtocols' : applicability: Applicable
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:01.998 [CBS]                       ...'RasServer' : applicability: Applicable
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:02.906 [CbsUIHandler]              Initiate:
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:02.906 [InstallationProgressPage]  Installing...
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:54.311 [CbsUIHandler]              Error: -2147023293 :
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:54.313 [CbsUIHandler]              Terminate:
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:54.316 [InstallationProgressPage]  Verifying installation...
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:54.326 [CBS]                       ...done installing 'IAS NT Service RasServerAll RasRoutingProtocols '. Status: -2147023293 (80070643)
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:54.329 [NPAS]                      Skipped configuration of 'Network Policy Server' because install operation failed.
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:54.330 [NPAS]                      Skipped configuration of 'Remote Access Service' because install operation failed.
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:54.330 [NPAS]                      Skipped configuration of 'Routing' because install operation failed.
2504: 2009-11-23 11:12:54.330 [Provider]                 
[STAT] ---- CBS Session Consolidation -----
[STAT] For
          'Network Policy Server',
          'Remote Access Service',
          'Routing'[STAT] installation(s) took '52.616957' second(s) total.
[STAT] Configuration(s) took '0.0004948' second(s) total.
[STAT] Total time: '52.6174518' second(s).
```

**From System Event Viewer...**

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          23/11/2009 11:12:23
Event ID:      7023
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Av7Analytics
Description:
The Network Policy Server service terminated with the following error:
%%-2147013892
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7023</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2009-11-23T11:12:23.653578500Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1317</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="468" ThreadID="2308" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Av7Analytics</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">Network Policy Server</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">%%-2147013892</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

**From Setup Event Viewer...**

```
Log Name:      Setup
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-ServerManager
Date:          23/11/2009 11:12:56
Event ID:      1616
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:     
User:          AV7ANALYTICS\RenamedAdmin
Computer:      Av7Analytics
Description:
Installation failed.

Roles:

Network Policy and Access Services
   Error: Attempt to install Network Policy Server failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
   Error: Attempt to install Remote Access Service failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
   Error: Attempt to install Routing failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
   The following role services were not installed:
   Network Policy Server
   Routing and Remote Access Services
      Remote Access Service
      Routing


Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-ServerManager" Guid="{8C474092-13E4-430E-9F06-5B60A529BF38}" />
    <EventID>1616</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2009-11-23T11:12:56.046431200Z" />
    <EventRecordID>115</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="2504" ThreadID="2344" />
    <Channel>Setup</Channel>
    <Computer>Av7Analytics</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-2753803390-1569373846-1208217686-500" />
  </System>
  <UserData>
    <EventXML xmlns:auto-ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events" xmlns="Event_NS">
      <message>

Roles:

Network Policy and Access Services
   Error: Attempt to install Network Policy Server failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
   Error: Attempt to install Remote Access Service failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
   Error: Attempt to install Routing failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
   The following role services were not installed:
   Network Policy Server
   Routing and Remote Access Services
      Remote Access Service
      Routing

</message>
      <identifiers>14, 206, 207, 208, 205</identifiers>
    </EventXML>
  </UserData>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

It's quite shocking that we're already having problems with Microsoft's "latest and greatest".

**Update:**

I have no idea what caused this error, but it eventually went away. I think it was when I installed other roles first (maybe Application, can't quite remember). It's certainly a weird bug! But I do have NPAS installed on my 2008 machines now, so it worked in the end. Sorry that's not anymore help :( –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

I have no idea what caused this error, but it eventually went away. I think it was when I installed other roles first (maybe Application, can't quite remember). It's certainly a weird bug! But I do have NPAS installed on my 2008 machines now, so it worked in the end.

Sorry that's not anymore help :(